# How to avoid Default value (com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@28e67c) for textfield in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl

I am working on a struts2 application. In one of the JSP page I have a textfield tag for which value is retrieved from OGNL expression. When the OGNL expression value is empty it is showing `com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@28e67c` in the text field. I do not want this default value, if the value is not available I want to show just empty textbox. Below is my code. Please help.

In the below example when the sampletext is empty I get some default value for textfield as `com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultTextProvider@28e67c` but I want to show it blank if it is empty.

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" errorPage="Error.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
 <%
  String sampletext = ""; 
 %>
 <html>
  <head>
  </head>
   <body>
     <s:set var="remarks"><%=sampletext%></s:set>
     <s:textfield value="%{remarks}" type="text"></s:textfield>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Don't use scriplets. If you are using S2 tags then don't use jstl tags.

Comment: Do you have `remarks` variable in your action? If yes show how do you populate it and its getter/setter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have remarks variable in my action. Below is the code is to populate it. Just to let you know populating/setting of remarks variable in action is fine, I am facing problem with the default value populated in the textfield.   

Action Class:
                                                                                 
    private String remarks;
    public String getRemarks() {
  return remarks;
 }

 public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
  this.remarks = remarks;
 }

Comment: Add code to your post by clicking edit link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use scriptlets in the code as @AleksandrM is mentioned, but you could use JSTL in the following way

```
 <c:set var="remarks"><%=sampletext%></c:set>
 <s:textfield value="%{#attr.remarks}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works fine once I use JSTL.

Comment: And also I will consider your suggestion of removing scriplet from the code.